# Generating Even Random Numbers

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, random, numbers

I need a code to generate only random EVEN numbers    2-100
There is tutorials on the web that generate random numbers but they're odd and even. 
Please understand i just need even numbers to generate.

Comment: Simply generate a random number between 1 and 50, and multiply it by 2.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what on earth this has to do with 1) an `iPhone` and 2) the `xcode IDE`??

Comment: im new this any of this. Im making an app on xcode for iphone.

Comment: @user3542263 The point being made by Popeye is that tags should reflect the question. Your question has nothing at all to do with Xcode (an IDE) or iPhone (a physical device). Your question is about writing code in Objective-C dealing with random numbers.

Comment: Actually, the question is about 4th-grade arithmetic. Maybe computer programming isn't the best choice for your future.

Comment: People seem to have completely missed the most important part of this question `"I need a **CODE** to generate only random EVEN numbers 2-100"` so they are not asking for an explanation of the algorithm they aren't asking for 4th-grade arithmetics solution they are asking specifically for **CODE**. So yes it might be 4th-grade arithmetics but they aren't asking for for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
NSInteger evenNumber = (arc4random_uniform(50) + 1) * 2;
```

`arc4random_uniform(50)` will give results in the range 0 - 49. Adding 1 gives a value in the range 1 - 50. Multiplying by two gives you even numbers in the range 2 - 100.

Answer (score 5):

1, generate numbers 1-50

2, multiply all the numbers by 2

all numbers multiplied by 2 are even

Comment: You going to give a coding related answer or is this it?

Comment: @Popeye The question is tagged as 'algorithm'. There is nothing wrong in explaining what should be done and let the OP understand the rest on his own, especially since he established he knows how to find 'odd and even' numbers.

Comment: @amit note that the original tags on this question when this answer appeared were `xcode` and `iphone` (Whilst these are wrong anyway) it does imply still that they are after a coding related answer.

Comment: @Popeye there is no way better than explaining an algorithm in plain english. It upto OP to implement it in his desired programming language.

Comment: @VikramBhat again the user was asking for code not an explanation of an algorithm.